# Why has this character's death been removed from the Italian theatrical version of Eva 3.0+1.0?

Tags: censorship, copyright, rebuild-of-evangelion

I've recently seen the Italian theatrical version of Eva 3.0+1.0 and I was very surprised to discover

> [Rei's death scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jDw1MgIaEc)

had been completely removed from the movie.

I frankly can't understand why they did something like that: it made the movie more difficult to understand and basically worked as a plot hole, because without

> Rei's death dialogue

it makes no sense at all for Shinji to come back and fight the last battle.

I would like to know why this happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distributor [Nexo Digital has affirmed this has happened due to an error](https://www.facebook.com/NexoDigital/posts/pfbid021YgjKyNkByk4EGhuMAhNXVJ7X8rKD239mTQh1BaeU5n6GMUvuegvCsXdEpntNUFQl), so at the very least this is true:

> A seguito delle numerose segnalazioni, e dopo un’opportuna verifica, confermiamo di avere riscontrato che alcune copie difettose di “Evangelion 3.0 + 1.01 Thrice Upon A Time” sono state erroneamente consegnate ai cinema dal laboratorio.
> Grazie anche al vostro aiuto, ci siamo attivati immediatamente per risolvere la problematica, inviando a tutti cinema un pacchetto correttivo per rimediare all’errore. Purtroppo non tutte le sale sono riuscite nella serata di ieri a provvedere per tempo alla correzione.
> Vogliamo rassicurare che oggi i cinema hanno provveduto a sostituire le copie errate, ci scusiamo con tutti i nostri spettatori per l’imprevisto che non è dipeso dalla volontà di Nexo Digital, né da Dynit.

Translation (Deepl):

> As a result of numerous reports, and after appropriate verification, we confirm that we have found that some defective copies of "Evangelion 3.0 + 1.01 Thrice Upon A Time" were mistakenly delivered to theaters by the lab.
> Thanks in part to your help, we took immediate action to resolve the issue, sending all theaters a corrective package to remedy the error. Unfortunately, not all theaters were able on yesterday evening to provide the correction in time.
> We would like to reassure you that today the theaters have replaced the erroneous copies; we apologize to all our viewers for the unforeseen situation, which was not the fault of Nexo Digital, nor of Dynit.

Also yes, you are among the very few people on the planet who can say to have witnessed a "canonical" timeline of Eva 3.0 + 1.0 in which Rei never dies.